# Word or term for a bet where you have nothing to lose

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word or compact term for a bet where you are **guaranteed** to get your input back?

> Say you bet $1 on a dice roll and get $1 for each eye on the dice roll. Since the dice has a minimum of one eye, you are getting your input of $1 back no matter what.

This of course is a very bad bet for the bank.

But how is that called?

Comment: A safe bet ?....

Comment: @Josh61 Make that an answer. But as a non-native I always thought a safe bet was a bet with a **very high* winning probability, but not 100%.

Comment: A safe bet:  a bet that is certain to succeed.
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/safe-bet

Comment: @Lars: Logically, if the probability is 100% that should be conveyed by ***it's a racing cert*** or ***a sure thing***. But in practice whenever someone gives you an assurance like that, you start looking for the pitfalls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[A sure thing](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sure+thing):

> An outcome that is certain or assured; a certainty; something guaranteed to be successful; something that is or should be a certain success, as a bet. - TFD
>
> > The Picasso Signature Is Still a Sure Thing - NYT

Also, a *foregone conclusion*:

> An end or a result regarded as inevitable:

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that even qualifies as bet.

A bet usually implies the risk of losing the initial money, but in this case the risk is just not there.